# CSS select all with sibling combinator

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, prototypejs

Using Prototype.js when I have an element and want to select all siblings after it of a certain tag type, would just do:

```
element.getElementsBySelector("~ tagName")
```

Where **tagName** could be **a** or **input** etc.

But what if I want to select **all** tag siblings after said element of any tag type?

I thought that:

```
element.getElementsBySelector("~ *")
```

Would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Why don't you use `element.nextSiblings()` instead?

Comment: Ah, thanks, wow kind of dumb of me :P

Comment: Although, now that I think about it, this would be nice to employ into a css file, I might need this down the road, but for now this works.

Comment: Just for completeness sake -- `nextSiblings()` gets all the siblings after the current element in the DOM, `previousSiblings()` before the element, and `siblings()` gets all of the siblings of the element in DOM order